# What's the difference between "with journal administrator" and "with editor?" in submission portal (Taylor and Francis)

Tags: paper-submission

Would I get desk rejected by the journal administrator, or the editor? What exactly is the difference between the two? (For Taylor and Francis journals)

Comment: see also https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/55665/what-does-the-typical-workflow-of-a-journal-look-like-how-should-i-interpret-a

Comment: Yes, these do answer it, thanks! I try not to ask redundant questions but unfortunately those didn't show up in Google search (I did spend about half an hour searching before asking).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, the journal administrator checks if you have uploaded everything necessary, i.e., if there is a legible paper there. The check here is not academic but more to see if it is spam, if it makes sense.

The editor is the editor; they will make the first decision on your paper. From there, the editor can either desk reject it or send it to the reviewers.

Obligatory: do not spend time checking the status; you'll get an email when/if something worthwhile happens.

Answer (score 4):

Odds are the journal administrator is an employee of the publisher, and the editor is a member of the editorial board.

An employee of the publisher probably does not have relevant subject expertise, but they can still perform some checks (below). Not all of these will be done, a lot will depend on their diligence & time they have available.

- If your source files compile
- If there are any missing figures
- If the manuscript is written in comprehensible English
- Your background (possibly via Google, possibly via internal databases)
- If your manuscript is pseudoscientific
- Self-citation rate

Since these checks are so basic, if your manuscript is desk-rejected by the journal administrator, it implies something is seriously wrong - but it can happen.